# What are the three different ways negative numbers can be represented in Binary?

Tags: binary

I am new to Binary and we are learning it for my computer hardware class. Since I am just learning, I am not very sure how to represent negative numbers in binary.

I believe they are Signed magnitude, ones complement, and two's complement, but I need an example. I'm not really sure how to show how this is done exactly.

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)?  There are examples there and a separate page for each of the three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no shame in representing decimal -2 as binary -10. In computer science there are different ways to represent negative numbers.

Sometimes, in a method called one's compliment, in order to take the negative number you need to flip all of the bits; for example, 101 negated would be 010.

In a method called two's compliment, you start from the right, find the first '1', and invert all of the bits to the left of that '1': 10100**1**000 negated would be 01011**1**000

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Anyway, it really just depends on how you *want* to represent it.

Comment: Have you no shame, sir?

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.